# How to provide audio preview in Safari without loading file into memory

Tags: javascript, audio, safari, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a web page which allows users to select multiple .wav files using the file select button of a form.  Each .wav is then displayed using the following markup:

```
<audio src="blob:f3xyz808-1a65-440e-8e5f-b5djfht4ad1a" controls=""></audio>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox.  In Safari, however, if I try to load too many .wavs at once it stops loading.  Using the javascript console I can see that the memory that Safari is using grows with each .wav and can reach upwards of 2GB.  With Chrome, memory usage does not increase significantly.  So it seems like Chrome and FF stream the files from disk.  Is it possible to do this with Safari?

***EDIT:***  It looks like a possible solution to this first problem is to include: `preload="none"` in the audio tag

On separate but related note:  It seems like browsers decode the audio files, at least to some extent, when they are added to an audio tag, because if the file is invalid they complain.  Is it possible to access this decoded data without creating an audio buffer in memory.  Specifically, I want to create a graph of the files' volume level vs. time.  Currently, I do this by decoding the arrayBuffer using the web audio api.  This uses a lot of memory.  Is it possible to get volume level info from the .wav's raw binary data?

I realize this question has some shortcomings.  I am a little vague on some of the concepts.

Any tips or suggestions would be a great help.  Thank you.

Comment: thank you @notthetup.  Matt Diamond's method is an improvement.  By creating a DataView I can access the pcm data without decoding the ArrayBuffer which saves time.  Creating the ArrayBuffer, however, still loads the entire contents of the wave file into memory.  I'm trying to process as many as 40 wave files as quickly as possible so that can be upwards of 2GB.  It is starting to seem clear, though, that there is no way around this, and I am just going to have to process them 1 at a time and be careful to dereference old ArrayBuffers.  Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Ah yes. There is no "read file in chunks" type functionality.

Comment: @notthetup, well, there is blob.slice and I can create an ArrayBuffer from that.  But I don't see how that would help my cause.  I would still have to be careful how many slices I created at a time.

Comment: But you'll still need to have the Blob loaded into memory. I was thinking more of 'load the file into memory in chunks' type of an API. That way you could load chunks of the file into memory, analyze them and throw them away. That way you don't hold references to the entire file but just a single chunk.

Comment: But yes, it seems you're gonna have to do the files one by one.